# Posicionar correctamente con bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

me gustaría poder posicionar mi codigo similar a esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero por mucho que le doy vueltas no consigo hacerlo correctamente.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2  col-md-offset-1">
<img src="img.png" alt="img" id="img" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1 text-center">
<p>Descripcion de la imagen</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2 text-center">
<a class="btn btn-dark me-2" href="#" role="button" target="_blank"> boton</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2 text-center">
<a class="btn btn-dark me-2" href="#" role="button" target="_blank"> boton</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He realizado algunos cambios significativos en tú código, como dejar dos div class="col", y dentro de la segunda columna agregar dos class="row" , uno para el texto y otro para los botones(btn-group).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<img text-right style="height:100px;width: 100%; max-width: 250px; min-height: 70px; height: auto;" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="img" id="img" />
</div>
<div class="col text-left">
<div class="row">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim ....
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn btn-dark me-2" href="#" role="button" target="_blank"> boton</a>
<a class="btn btn-dark me-2" href="#" role="button" target="_blank"> boton</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por ayudarme!! esto era justo lo que necesitaba :)

Comment: Es un placer poder ayudarle amigo @WinterIsback

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo muy bien por donde quieres dejar la imagen, por lo que la he quitado.
Pero para el resto, puedes guiarte con el [grid-system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) de bootstrap.
Basta con asignar correctamente valores para obtener el resultado esperado.

Ahora bastará con que tu corrijas a lo que realmente quieras mostrar.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="height: 10vh">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_51056320928_3eb1e28ae8_320_240_nofilter.jpg" alt="img" id="img" width="100px" height="100px" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      Descripcion de la imagen
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col-10 text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-dark" href="#" role="button" target="_blank"> boton</a>
    <a class="btn btn-dark" href="#" role="button" target="_blank"> boton</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: la imagen es el cuadrado que se ve en la imagen de ejemplo

Comment: Si, pero donde la quieres, sobre la descripción, debajo de esta, a la izquierda, detras ??

Comment: no no, solo al lado igual que en el ejemplo que ocupe el rectangulo, el cuadrado dibujado, al lado izquierdo de la descripcion y los botones es la imagen

Comment: Algo aproximado a la edicion actual ?

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme ^^, si era eso jejejeje me ha servido mucho tambien tu respuesta, entre los dos he conseguido colocarlo bien!

Comment: de nada, para eso estamos.